# What is the best way to test Cassandra applications?

Tags: cassandra

I am currently using [Achilles Embedded](https://github.com/doanduyhai/Achilles) to spin up a local, temporary Cassandra instance and test my functionality there. While this is working to some extend, there seems to be a memory leak as the more tests I run, the more I see messages like `PS Scavenge GC in xx ms`, and my system slows to a crawl, even freezing the mouse pointer.

So, is there a better way to automatically spin up a small Cassandra instance to run my tests against?

Answer (score 1):

The tool I use for quickly creating a local Cassandra cluster is the ccm (Cassandra Cluster Manager) utility.  You can easily create a multi-node cluster on your local machine for any release.  See more information [here](http://www.planetcassandra.org/getting-started-with-ccm-cassandra-cluster-manager/).

I believe some of the Cassandra developers use ccm for their development work, so ccm is kept up to date with the newest releases.

Comment: I am now using cassandraunit, I only have to make sure not to close and re-open `Cluster`and `Session` too often.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, you can use use CCM. if you have a test cluster. Try using cassandra stress tool (Either standalone or using yam profile). If I am getting your question correct, it will solve your problem.